# How to get the number of elements separated by an underscore

Tags: r

```
strings<-c("A_A_A","B", "C_C_C_C", "D_D_D_D_D")
```

I have this vector of strings.
I want to have the number of elements in each string so that to have:

```
[1] 3  1  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
stringr::str_count(c("A_A_A","B", "C_C_C_C", "D_D_D_D_D"), '_') + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For a base R option, we could use string replacement:

```r
strings <- c("A_A_A","B", "C_C_C_C", "D_D_D_D_D")
nchar(strings) - nchar(gsub("_", "", strings, fixed=TRUE)) + 1

[1] 3 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lengths` with `strsplit`.

```r
strings <- c("A_A_A", "B", "C_C_C_C", "D_D_D_D_D")

lengths(strsplit(strings, split = "_"))
# [1] 3 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

strings<-c("A_A_A","B", "C_C_C_C", "D_D_D_D_D")

strings %>% 
  str_remove_all("_") %>% 
  str_count

#> [1] 3 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `nchar` + `gsub`

```
> nchar(gsub("[^_]", "", strings)) + 1
[1] 3 1 4 5
```

or

```
> nchar(gsub("_", "", strings))
[1] 3 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is always like your sample data, that means 1 character seperated by one length seperator you can simply do

```
ceiling(nchar(strings)/2)

# [1] 3 1 4 5
```

or

```
nchar(strings)%/%2+1

# [1] 3 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify the types of characters that you want to count. So, in this case, we can just count the alphabetic characters (i.e., `"[[:alpha:]]"`). Or if you also have numbers, then could use `"[[:alnum:]]"`.

```
library(stringr)

str_count(strings, "[[:alpha:]]")
# [1] 3 1 4 5
```

Or in base R:

```
nchar(gsub("([^[:alpha:]])+", "", strings))
# [1] 3 1 4 5
```